# Homestead No input File specified

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

So I am trying to setup homestead on my windows machince but I keep getting the 'No input file specified' but im prettu sure I got the path corretly because they where working before. My homestead yaml file is like the following.

```
folders:
    - map: C:\Users\Steve\Dropbox\Work\Laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/
sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

Now the files are syncing between one another and inside of Laravel I have another Laravel folder which contains the frameowrk.

When i run homestead.app I get the error and as you can see in the screenshot below the paths are matching together. If you shed some light I would greatly  appreciate.

I have tried homestead destroy and homestead destroy multiple time.

[image]

Comment: You are using wrong slashes use like this :  / as C:/Users/Steave/Dropbox/Work/Laravel